# What is this extra vent in my window called?

Tags: windows

Two of my windows and my sliding door have this extra vent thing installed on them. The vent can open and close to (I'm assuming) let a bit of air into the room without opening the whole window.

I never use these, but one of them does not seal properly and the other is fully broken. I can't figure out what to google to find spare parts. Does anyone know what these are called?

The windows are made by Milgard and I believe they were put in in the early 2000s. I don't see these things on their modern windows so I'm wondering if these were a limited time feature before someone realized that it was a dumb idea.

[image: Window vent thing]

Comment: forced ventilation ?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a cover for an accessory mounting slot?

Comment: Looks like a pop-up/fold-down **handle** from this picture, to me.

Comment: Actually, you can see holes under the flat piece. Here in NZ  we had a radically different version for a while.

Comment: Definitely not a handle - it's very flimsy and pops up to reveal a vent to the outside. I'm not sure what accessories would fit there either. The forced ventilation thing sounds the most plausible, but when I search for "Milgard window vent" nothing like this comes up...

Comment: I'll email milgard directly to see if they can help. Probably should've done that first

Comment: Found this as a possible name after looking for window vents.  window trickle vents.  Will probably need to buy from milgard anyway.

Comment: Is this a double glazed window? This may allow air to circulate between the inner and outer glazing to clear moisture.

Comment: My building, constructed in 2000, is LEED certified and the units each have multiple exhaust fans. The units have similar vents on the windows, presumably to allow air to flow in to replace the outflow from the exhaust fans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a "trickle vent".  If you leave it open, it allows a bit of ventilation even when the main window is closed.